# Resizing of image using CvMat In Open CV

Tags: c, opencv, resize, resize-image

I am using `CvMat` and `cvResize` function in Open CV to add two images of different size.

```
CvMat *ob1 =cvLoadImageM("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Koala.jpg");
CvMat *ob2 = cvLoadImageM("C:\\Users\\tgupta\\Downloads\\len_std256.jpg");
cvResize(ob1,ob2,CV_INTER_LINEAR);
CvMat *dst=NULL;
dst = cvCreateMat(ob1->rows,ob1->cols,CV_8UC3);
cvSetZero(dst);
cvAdd(ob2,ob1,dst);
cvShowImage( "cv_src",dst);
```

But in this when I am using the `cvResize` function the values of `ob2` does not re-size to `ob1` and my program crashes at `cvAdd` because of the different sizes of image.  Please tell me where I am doing wrong in this or tell me another solution using `CvMat` structure.  Please don't tell solutions for `Mat` or `IplImage` structure.

Comment: please use opencv's c++ api, not the deprecated c-one.

Comment: Actually I need to work on c structures only instead of c++ .

Comment: then, do **not** use opencv.

Comment: Instead of telling the solution why are you suggesting for Mat structures.I already mentioned I don't have to use Mat .If you have done it using CvMat then please answer it or tell me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: you'r e doing wrong using CvMat for images

Comment: then please tell me where I am doing wrong .And please write the code for it like you did for Mat ,it would be really helpful .

Comment: Added code tags to your variables in your text.  Made you bottom paragraph more clear

Comment: `cvResize(ob1,ob2,CV_INTER_LINEAR);` so, you're already overwriting your 2nd image with the resized 1nd one. and you're supposed to use IplImage for images in C. and the C-api died half a decade ago. - you're doing it wrong all the way. stop that moronic thing now.

Answer (score 0):

really, you *must* use the c++ api:

```
Mat ob1 = imread("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Koala.jpg");
Mat ob2 = imread("C:\\Users\\tgupta\\Downloads\\len_std256.jpg");
resize(ob1, ob1, ob2.size()); // change size of ob1 to the one of ob2

Mat dst; 
add(ob1,ob2,dst);
imshow("cv_src",dst);
waitKey();
```

Comment: There is some restriction in my project which I am working on .I have to use C structures only .I know using Mat and IplImage resizing can be done easily .But please tell me how to do it for CvMat structure .